# usb4java USB error 4: Unable to open USB device:

Tags: java, usb, libusb, usb4java

I am attempting to interface with the PS3's DS3 controller. I have managed to do so in `C#` using an implementation of `libusb` but decided to move my implementation to `java`. Unfortunately my move to java has not been so smooth. The device seems to be found in the device list but when I attempt to open it I get the following error **" USB error 4: Unable to open USB device: No such device (it may have been disconnected)"**

```
public class Main {
private static final short VID = 0x054c;
private static final short PID = 0x0268;

Context context;

public Main() {
    context = new Context();
    int result = LibUsb.init(context);

    if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialize libusb.", result);
    }

    ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(49);
    DeviceHandle ds3Handle = getDeviceHandle(findDevice(VID, PID));
    LibUsb.controlTransfer(ds3Handle, (byte)0xa1, (byte)0x1, (short)0x101, (short)0, data, 1000L);

    LibUsb.exit(context);
}

private Device findDevice(int vid, int pid) {
    Device UsbDevice = null;
    DeviceList list = new DeviceList();
    int result = LibUsb.getDeviceList(context, list);

    if (result < 0) {
        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device list", result);
    } 

    try {
        for(Device device: list) {
            DeviceDescriptor descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
            result = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, descriptor);

            if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
                throw new LibUsbException("Unable to read device descriptor", result);
            } 

            if (descriptor.idVendor() == vid && descriptor.idProduct() == pid) {
                UsbDevice = device;
                System.out.println("found");
            }
        }
    } finally {
        LibUsb.freeDeviceList(list, true);
    }

    return UsbDevice;
}

private DeviceHandle getDeviceHandle(Device device) {
    DeviceHandle handle = new DeviceHandle();
    int result = LibUsb.open(device, handle);

    if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to open USB device", result);
    }

    return handle;
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    new Main();
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LibUsb.freeDeviceList(list, true);

That `true` is the problem. "final boolean unrefDevices" is shown in javadoc. Your code is releasing the Device before you have a chance to open it.

Comment: Can confirm, this is the solution to OP's problem. Just encountered the same issue using the same sample code from `usb4java`'s page. Much appreciated!

Comment: Their website is on GitHub.  Issued a PR. https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java.github.io/pull/2

Comment: It seems that the error is indeed caused by the release of the devices, but how do I actually fix this? When I change my true into false, it gives another error.

Answer (score 1):

Just changing to false it is not enough you also need to call refDevice with the device you need to return
example:

```
    } finally {
        // Ensure the allocated device list is freed
        LibUsb.freeDeviceList(list, false);
    }

    if (deviceFound != null) {
        // Device found
        LibUsb.refDevice(deviceFound);
    }
    return deviceFound;
```